# Using strftime to format datetime.timedelta objects in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, iteration, datetime-format

So say i have some `datetime.timedelta objects` stored in a dictionary and I plan on writing them to and output .txt file. I prefer this output file to be easily readable as to obtain information from it without wasting much time. So i definitely want to format these with something close to this i assume:

`a_time_obj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

I also assume i will have to iterate over each object which I'm not quite sure how to do with with these `datetime.timedelta` objects. Can it be done? If so, what's the most pythonic way to accomplish this?

This is what i currently get as output when i write to a .txt file:

> {'Monday': 0, 'Tuesday': 0, 'Friday': 0, 'Wednesday':
>   datetime.timedelta(0, 18, 496000), 'Thursday': 0, 'Sunday': 0,
>   'Saturday': 0}

**EDIT** --  code:

```
for key, value in get_weekly_hours.iteritems():
    formatted_value = value.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
return formatted_value
```

Error message:
for key, value in get_weekly_hours.iteritems():
        formatted_value = value.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return formatted_value Attribute:Error 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: can you put an example of your timedelta objects dict?

Comment: yeah on it one second please

Comment: Is `a_time_obj` a list?

Comment: no just an arbitrary datetime object

Comment: @After_Sunset read my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: Your example dict contains both int values AND datetime.timedelta values. This is almost certainly not what you mean to do. Initialize your dict with datetime.timedelta() (a 00:00:00 delta) instead of with the value 0.

Instead of  {'Monday': 0} you would store {'Monday': timedelta.datetime()}

```
d = {}
d['key1'] = datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=1, seconds=1)
d['key2'] = datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=2, seconds=2)
d['key3'] = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=3, seconds=3)
```

-- print the values, rely on the default string representation of datetime.timedelta --

```
def serialize_dict(d):
  for key,value in d.iteritems():
  print '%s: %s' % (key,value)
serialize_dict(d)
#
# output:
# key3: 3:03:03
# key2: 2:02:02
# key1: 1:01:01
```

--or write to a file --

```
def serialize_dict(d):
  with open('/tmp/output', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
      f.write('%s: %s\n' % (key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a dict of timedelta objects called `your_dict`. You can iterate over it with this code

```
for key, value in your_dict.iteritems():
       a_time_obj_str = value.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
       //write your date string in your file
```

Comment: @After_Sunset ok, you are iterating over your deltatime objects dict, that solved your problem ?